# Thunderbird download indicator for Unity?

Tags: unity, 12.04, thunderbird, downloads

Firefox has a great Unity progress bar when stuff downloads. However, Thunderbird hasn't. (Or does it?)

Is there a Thunderbird progress bar available for Thunderbird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firefox feature is integrated with the newest version of Ubuntu to date (12.04).

An add-on for Thunderbird was made during 11.04 days and that url can be found below:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/unity-unread-count/

This feature has been added into the Ubuntu Thunderbird build since and currently works (Ubuntu Thunderbird Version: `12.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1`)

---

The download status bar feature is not a feature yet made in either the standard Ubuntu build or as a Thunderbird add-on at this point. Some ways to get this feature added to the next build of Ubuntu's Thunderbird would be by asking the question about a download status bar to the Ubuntu Mozilla Team here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+addquestion

Another way to get this feature added would be to create an add-on for Thunderbird that would just help with the download status bar option for Unity and see if this feature will be added in the future (but can be used now if developed correctly).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This add-on is for 11.04. In 12.04 both the features this add-on offers are already available in Thunderbird.

Comment: When I download an attachment, no progress bar appears in the Unity Thunderbird icon.

Comment: @BasharatSial that is good to know and I didn't see it on my implementation of Thunderbird. Will have to try it again (clean install) and make sure it works.

Comment: @Gonzoza Like I said in my response, nothing was found to have had the feature you want in it. You could see if the developer of the Thunderbird counter would add it on or see if the Thunderbird launchpad project would support that feature (https://launchpad.net/thunderbird). Right now, a download status bar on the Unity icon isn't a feature yet.

Comment: @BasharatSial Your right, just needed to wait for a new email to come in through Thunderbird and it came up with the counter. Will update the reply with a better answer.

Comment: Updated with better information related to the features that are already in use and how others can be added.